# setting smoothing parameters in d3 js smoothing splines

Tags: d3.js, smoothing, splines

I'm trying to set the smoothing parameters (lambda) using one of the smoothing libraries in the d3 js (d3.curveBasis, curveBasisClosed ...etc), but I'm not sure how to do it. The following is exactly what I want -

http://bl.ocks.org/jonahwilliams/62be9996afe5c2531625

However, my x axis has dates and this doesn't seem to handle it well. I'm, ideally, looking for ways to modify existing libraries to add the smoothing parameter, lambda. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Kindly show us that you tried something already, e.g. by showing your code and explain unexpected or wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

D3.js (Version 4)

```
var line = d3.line()
.curve(d3.curveMonotoneX) <-- Insert smoothing here
.x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
```

D3.js (Version 3)

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("monotone")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
```

Perform the smoothing directly on the line you're plotting.